Weird glowing artefact on render
Got this on my render, anyone seen something like this before?

Hello, are you sure that you have not disabled an object for preview and not for render?

I rendered the same scene before without making any changes and it was ok, but I'll check anyway

Looks like the problem was caused by glare node in compositing - the glowing spot disappeared after I disabled it.
